# Why FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON doesn't work properly?

Tags: android, android-intent, android-notifications, android-notification-bar

I am trying to make the screen to be always on while my test app is in the foreground with Ongoing Notification running.
It works fine when the app is on resume state, but it doesn't work when I hit the home/middle button to put the app on pause state while showing up the Ongoing notification in the notification status bar.

Why `getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON)` does not work in the foreground/pause state?

MainActivity:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);

    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    ...

    NotificationCompat.Builder OnGoingStatusBar = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
    OnGoingStatusBar.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.image);
    OnGoingStatusBar.setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.ic_launcher));            
    OnGoingStatusBar.setTicker(Test);           
    OnGoingStatusBar.setContentTitle("Test");
    OnGoingStatusBar.setContentText("Testing Message");         
    OnGoingStatusBar.setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis());
    OnGoingStatusBar.setAutoCancel(false);
    OnGoingStatusBar.setContent(notificationView).build();
    OnGoingStatusBar.setOngoing(true);   //Create OnGoing Status Bar
    OnGoingStatusBar.setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_MAX);
    NotificationManager.notify(STATUSBAR_ID, OnGoingStatusBar.build());
}
```

Comment: It only works when the app has a window, i.e. when the user can see its UI.

Comment: `getWindow()`. You have a window only when visible

Comment: thanks for the response.  Is there any workaround that I can achieve my goal?  I know this works on older Android version:      pm = (PowerManager) getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
     km = (KeyguardManager)getSystemService(Context.KEYGUARD_SERVICE);
     mKeyguardLock = km.newKeyguardLock("INFO");     
     mWakeLock = pm.newWakeLock(PowerManager.FULL_WAKE_LOCK | 
              PowerManager.ACQUIRE_CAUSES_WAKEUP|PowerManager.ON_AFTER_RELEASE, "INFO");
     
     mKeyguardLock.disableKeyguard();// dismiss the keyguard
     mWakeLock.acquire();

Comment: ugg, the code doesn't look good in comment section...

Answer (score 2):

You should move  `getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON)` below `setContentView()` and put `android:keepScreenOn="true"` into the root View of your main layout .

The documentation on this topic might be usefull: https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/wakelock.html#screen

Comment: Thanks for the comment.  I followed your suggestion, but there is no change.  The screen still turns off whenever the activity is not visible / foreground/onPause state.  Thanks

Comment: @YRTM2014 You are describing the intended functionality. See https://developer.android.com/training/scheduling/wakelock.html

Comment: KeepScreenOn doesnt actually work for me, it still goes to sleep.